# When compiling, what does the numbers in brackets refer to?

Tags: compiling, logging

When compiling a file via `pdflatex` (maybe it also is true for the other cases), the output to the command line shows a series of increasing numbers in brackets, like

```
[13] (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-euf.cfg)
[14] [15] [16] [17] [18]
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/doublestroke/Udsrom.fd) [19]
[20]
```

These also appear in the `.log` file.

What do they refer to?

Also, there are empty brackets appearing, for instance

```
Overfull \hbox (60.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 231--231
 [] [] 
  []
```

What do they belong to?

Comment: the page number

Comment: Ah, great. Now I remember. I would like to add an edit to the question, as there are also empty brackets appearing…

Comment: An overfull hbox message is followed by an approximate representation of the box contents; `[]` is used when the contents cannot be represented on the terminal (for instance, an inner box).

Comment: Great, everything answered in the comments. Would anyone of you put it together to an answer so that I can mark it answered? Or should I do it myself?

Comment: @egreg Are you aware of a suitabe duplicate question? If not, please write up an answer.

Comment: @egreg Would you like to give an answer? See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7248/what-is-the-etiquette-for-providing-an-answer-already-in-the-comments

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every time TeX ejects a page (writing in the DVI/PDF file and removing the page material from its memory), it will record the fact in the log file by writing

```
[<page number>]
```

where `<page number>` is the current value of `\count0`. In LaTeX, `\value{page}` is the same as `\count0`.

<sub>Actually, all counters from `\count0` to `\count9` are recorded, but only the values up to the last nonzero value are written in the log file. So, if `\count0`, `\count2` and `\count3` have the value 4, 0 and 2, with the following counters being 0, `[4.0.2]` would be shown</sub>

The (square) bracket notation is also used for showing box contents. For instance, when an overfull/underfull box message is issued, a representation of the offending box is shown. From a test I was doing, I got

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 25--25
|[]\TU/lmr/m/it/10 su-per-cal-
```

on the terminal and

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 25--25
|[]\TU/lmr/m/it/10 su-per-cal-
 []
```

in the log file.

The empty group `[]` at the beginning represents items that cannot be shown in details (most often they're boxes or whatsits). The `|` stands for a rule.

The trailing `[]` can only be seen in the log file and not in the terminal output. It stands for the detailed representation of the overfull/underfull box; the level of details is controlled by the parameters `\showboxdepth` and `\showboxbreadth`, which LaTeX sets to −1. If we increase their values we can see much more in the log file:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 25--25
|[]\TU/lmr/m/it/10 su-per-cal-

\hbox(8.39996+3.60004)x56.9055, direction TLT
.\rule(8.39996+3.60004)x0.0
.\whatsit3121978=5
.\kern3.0
.\glue 0.0
.\TU/lmr/m/it/10 s
.\TU/lmr/m/it/10 u
.\discretionary (penalty 50)
..< \TU/lmr/m/it/10 -
.\TU/lmr/m/it/10 p
.\kern -0.51
.\TU/lmr/m/it/10 e
.\TU/lmr/m/it/10 r
.\discretionary (penalty 50)
..< \TU/lmr/m/it/10 -
..= \kern -0.51
.\TU/lmr/m/it/10 c
.\kern -0.51
.\TU/lmr/m/it/10 a
.\TU/lmr/m/it/10 l
.\TU/lmr/m/it/10 -
.\discretionary (penalty 50)
.\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
```

(here LuaTeX was used, but it doesn't differ from the other engines in this respect).

So you see that `[]` in the short representation stands for a combination of a whatsit, kern and glue.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! So basically this is the output on the plain TeX level that's shown here, right? Where does one specify the parameters `\showboxbreath` and `\showboxdepth`? Just set them in the preamble via `\showboxdepth=10`? The TeXbyTopic manual refers also to a command `\tracingonline` which should also put this output to the command line. Is this also just set in the preamble?

Comment: @jjdb The value of the parameters can be set wherever you want to. They affect subsequent output subject to the normal scoping rules.

Comment: thanks again. So one could use these before and after a section that caused an overfull hbox warning for debugging? I also found the `logbox` package. This seems useful, too. But how would I be able to see what caused the warning, eg in your example?